# Play! framework 1.2.4, dependencies and Netbeans 7

Tags: netbeans, playframework

I switched to the "new" dependency system in Play! Framework. I'm using Netbeans 7. In Netbeans, all my code compiles and there are no complaints. My site also runs nicely if I start it from the terminal. However, if I run it from Netbeans, I get some runtime errors (in this case it complains about some Excel 1.2.3 / Apache POI packages):

Compilation error

The file /app/controllers/Admin.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet cannot be resolved

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
```

Any one encountered this problem (or similar)?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have not added your poi lib to the Netbeans project classpath.

If you added the lib after doing a netbeansify, you should do again a netbeansify, then reimport the project into Netbeans.

Comment: Netbeans find the packages. But there's something about how the site is started from Netbeans, I think. I did a "play dependencies" before "play netbeansify". (so I did not add the lib after doing netbeansify)